# Two columns into one while keeping other columns. Then merge with another table

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables:

```
//             friendships
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|      fid        |     person1     |     person2     | 
|-----------------+-----------------|-----------------+
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|       1         |    personid     |   personid      |
|-----------------+-----------------|-----------------+
|       2         |    personid     |   personid      |
|-----------------+-----------------|-----------------+

//             persons
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|      pid        |     firstname   |     lastname    | 
|-----------------+-----------------|-----------------+
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|       1         |    name         |    name         |
|-----------------+-----------------|-----------------+
|       2         |    name         |     name        |
|-----------------+-----------------|-----------------+
```

1 ) I want to get all rows in the friendships table which contain a certain personid. This id can be either in the person1 or person2 column. The `fid` column should be preserved, but the `person` columns should only be one, e.g.:

```
 Select fid, person1 as person, person2 as person FROM friendships
 WHERE person1 = some_personid
 OR person2 = some_personid;
```

(the 2 person columns from this query should be only one). How do I do that?

2) I want to join the persons table on the result from step 1 `ON fid.person = persons.pid`.

Comment: Is the friendship relationship symmetrical? I mean if A is friend of B, is also B friend of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want first name and last name of every friend of the desired person, whether this person is under `person1` or `person2`.

In that case, if the friendship relationship is not symmetrical you can do that with a subquery

```
select  *
from    persons p
join    (
            select  fid, person1 as person, person2 as otherPerson
            from    friendship
            where   person1 = 'yourPerson'
            union all
            select  fid, person2 as person, person1 as otherPerson
            from    friendship
            where   person2 = 'yourPerson'
        ) f
 on    p.pid = f.otherPerson
```

If its symmetrical, the query is much easier, since every row with the desired person under `person2` will have a corresponding row with the desired person under `person1`.

```
select  *
from    friendship f
join    person p
on      f.person2 = p.pid
where   person1 = 'yourPerson'
```

Answer (score 1):

For step one, use an OR clause in your where filter to indicate which records should be kept. Then use a case statement in your select to pick which person.

```
select    fid
        , case person1 when some_personid then person1 else person2 end as person
    from friendships
    where (person1 = some_personid
        or person2 = some_personid)
```

For step two, you select from persons and join onto the table from step 1 using a subquery.

```
select *
    from persons p
    inner join (
        select    fid
                , case person1 when some_personid then person1 else person2 end as person
            from friendships
            where (person1 = some_personid
                or person2 = some_personid)
    ) f on f.person = p.pid
```

Hope this helps!